# Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm working with rails for a while and lately I encounter one quite serious & annoying problem. When I do any `rails` command I get this error:

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try:  gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
```

so I try the suggested `gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2` no error but nothing changed.

I checked those gems and they're installed and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 3):

ok so I did `gem update bundler
gem install curb` uninstalled ruby 2.1 installed it again and now I rails are workin fine